# how can i solve the forward kinematics and get the cartesian positions for the links on a arm?

Tags: ros, kinematics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi !
i have to control arm robot using ROS and  solve the forward kinematics and inverse kinematics .
how can i  solve the forward kinematics and get the cartesian positions for the links on a arm using ROS Jade ?
how can i connect arm robot to my ROS program and read positions  from the links on a arm using sensors ?
what is the best solution for  forward kinematics and inverse kinematics in ROS ?
please help me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243201/how-can-i--solve-the-forward-kinematics-and-get-the-cartesian-positions-for-the-links-on-a-arm?/) by [hosein_hyper](https://answers.ros.org/users/27843/hosein_hyper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest option is to create a URDF model for your robot and publish joint_state data to a robot_state_publisher ([tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher)). This will generate tf transform data for all frames, which is the same as forward kinematics. This is really meant for representing the current robot state however.

A very convenient option is [generating a MoveIt! config](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/moveit_setup_assistant/html/doc/tutorial.html) for the robot. The kinematics capabilities can then be used programmatically as described in the [kinematics tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/pr2_moveit_tutorials/html/kinematics/src/doc/kinematics_tutorial.html).

There are also other options like using [KDL](http://kdl), but I believe MoveIt! is probably the easiest to use.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3